# Table Printing Issue: Gaps in top and Bottom Border of th Elements

Tags: html, css, printing, css-tables

I have a table that I need to print.  I would like a solid 1px line above and below the header, and at the bottom of the table.

I've tried all the usual tricks:

```
border-collapse:collapse;
border-spacing:0;
```

etc.

But what I get is this:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PDzfw/)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

simple
use `cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"` in the table tag :)

so it be `<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">`

Comment: To do the same using CSS you can specify it like this:                                          
`table {
        border-spacing: 0; 
        padding: 0; 
         }`

Answer (score 0):

Adding these to the *table* element ought to fix it:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px;
}
```